# How do I get circe to have an either/or output scenario for the generated Json?

Tags: scala, circe

Here's what I intend - let's say I have a field called `medical_payments` - it can "either" be a *limit* if one elects or *waived*

```
{
  "medical_payments": 
    {
      "limit_value":"one_hundred"
    }
}
```

If it's elected as a waiver then it should be:

```
{
  "medical_payments": 
    {
      "waived":true
    }
}
```

So far here's what I have:

```
sealed trait LimitOrWaiver
case class Limit(limit_key: String) extends LimitOrWaiver
case class Waived(waived: Boolean) extends LimitOrWaiver

case class Selection(medical_payments: LimitOrWaiver)
```

Sample data:

```
Selection(medical_payments = Limit("one_hundred")).asJson
```

Output:

```
{
  "medical_payments": 
    {
      "Limit": { "limit_value":"one_hundred" } // additional object added
    }
}
```

Similarly for `Selection(medical_payments = Waived(true)).asJson` an additional `Waived:{...}` is added to the Json.

I'd like it to be an either/or. What's the best way to achieve this?

The only way that I've been able to think of (not to my liking) is to use `forProductN` functions [per the doc](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html#custom-key-mappings-via-annotations) and manually do all this - but it's way to cumbersome for a large Json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *almost* accomplish this with generic derivation using the configuration in generic-extras:

```
sealed trait LimitOrWaiver
case class Limit(limitValue: String) extends LimitOrWaiver
case class Waived(waived: Boolean) extends LimitOrWaiver
case class Selection(medicalPayments: LimitOrWaiver)

import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration, io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

implicit val codecConfiguration: Configuration =
  Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("type").withSnakeCaseMemberNames
```

And then:

```
scala> Selection(medicalPayments = Limit("one_hundred")).asJson
res0: io.circe.Json =
{
  "medical_payments" : {
    "limit_value" : "one_hundred",
    "type" : "Limit"
  }
}
```

(Note that I've also changed the Scala case class member names to be Scala-idiomatic camel-case, and am handling the transformation to snake-case in the configuration.)

This isn't exactly what you want, since there's that extra `type` member, but circe's generic derivation only supports round-trip-able encoders / decoders, and without a discriminator of some kind—either a member like this or the extra object layer you point out in the question—it's impossible to round-trip values of arbitrary ADTs through JSON.

This might be fine—you might not care about the extra `type` in your object. If you do care, you can still use derivation with a little extra work:

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration, io.circe.generic.extras.auto._
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._
import io.circe.ObjectEncoder, io.circe.syntax._

implicit val codecConfiguration: Configuration =
  Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("type").withSnakeCaseMemberNames

implicit val encodeLimitOrWaiver: ObjectEncoder[LimitOrWaiver] =
  deriveEncoder[LimitOrWaiver].mapJsonObject(_.remove("type"))
```

And:

```
scala> Selection(medicalPayments = Limit("one_hundred")).asJson
res0: io.circe.Json =
{
  "medical_payments" : {
    "limit_value" : "one_hundred"
  }
}
```

If you really wanted you could even make this automatic, so that `type` would be removed from any ADT encoders you derive.

Comment: This is really useful. I will have to remove `type` AFAIK. And for some reason `withSnakeCaseMember...` isn’t snaking nested objects. So have to keep supplying `deriveEncoders` for everything. Might as well remove `type` as you suggested. Sigh. I sometimes feel Circe is more of a headache than anything else :)

Comment: @PhD You don't have to use generic derivation!

Comment: YOU are a contributor to Circe?!? (Just saw your name in a few of the code files :)

Comment: You're gonna hate me for this. One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976376/how-to-get-circe-to-skip-certain-values-from-the-enumeration :D