# How to get Circe to skip certain values from the enumeration?

Tags: scala, circe

We have an "enumeration" like so:

```
sealed abstract class StatusEnumeration(val value: String)
case object Status {
  case object Mine extends StatusEnumeration("mine")
  case object Someone extends StatusEnumeration("someone")
  case object Neighbor extends StatusEnumeration("neighbor")
  case object Unknown extends StatusEnumeration("unknown")
}
```

This structure is dictated by our domain/needs. However, I'd like to convert this `StatusEnumeration` into an output JSON like so:

```
case class Root(status: StatusEnumeration)
```

I've set the following implicit encoder and it works as expected:

```
implicit val encoder = deriveEnumerationEncoder[StatusEnumeration]
```

However, *if* the `StatusEnumeration` is set to `Status.Unknown` I'd like for the value generation to be skipped Or just output a `null` instead (which I can then drop via `dropNullValues`). How can I do something like this? Is it even possible or do I need to redefine another set of enums?

So far this is what I was trying when @Alec also commented to try something similar:

```
implicit val encoder = deriveEnumerationEncoder[StatusEnumeration].mapJson(x=>{

    x.asString match {
      case Some("Unknown") => Json.Null
      case Some(s) => Json.fromString(s.toLowerCase) // output expect lowercase - not sure if the consumer is case-sensitive
      case None => Json.Null
    }

  })
```

This does seem to work as expected. Is this the recommended way or is there a better one?

Comment: How about something like `implicit val encoder = deriveEnumerationEncoder[StatusEnumeration].mapJson(json => json.asString match { case Some("Unknown") => Json.Null; case _ => json })`

Comment: @Alec - You beat me to it - was trying to *exactly* that do that to see if it'd work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried to compile this, but based on the Scaladocs you should be able to do:

```scala
implicit val encoder = Encoder.encodeOption(deriveEnumerationEncoder[StatusEnumeration])
  .contramap {
    case Unknown => None
    case known => Some(known)
  }
```

Basically, construct an encoder `Option[StatusEnumeration]`, then map `StatusEnumeration` onto that accordingly (I'm pretty sure the encoder for `Option` puts `None` as `null` and `Some(x)` as `x` encoded).